# Como podria hacer que mi programa de un numero de cuenta correlativo en vez de uno randomizado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, numpy, python-3.7

En este punto esta el comienzo del programa, la solucion primero que le di fue darle un randomizado de numeros, pero ahora el problema es el siguiente, si yo quiero que los numeros sea a partir del 1001 como me pide el enunciado, que debo hacer? una cosa que se me pasa por mi cabeza es de determinar que el numero vaya avanzando a traves de un contador, pero como hago para acoplar al numero de cuentas de la lista, cuando vuelva a ingresar una nueva cuenta, esa sera el mismo numero nuevamente y no me serviria de nada, cual podria ser una solucion? No se me ocurre nada llevo casi unos 45 mins pensando y estoy con intriga de como hacerlo, ayudaaaaaaaa :c

```
#EL NÚMERO DE LA CUENTA SE ASIGNARÁ DE MANERA CORRELATIVA A PARTIR DEL NÚMERO 1001.

import random 

listadeclientes=[]

class cuenta:
    def __init__(self,nombre,apellido,numc,ci,saldo):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.apellido=apellido
        self.numc=numc
        self.ci=ci
        self.saldo=saldo
    def desc(self):
        print("Nombre(s): ", self.nombre , "Apellidos: ", self.apellido ,"Numero de Cuenta: ", self.numc ,"CI: ", self.ci , "Saldo :", self.saldo)
    def csaldo(self):
        print(f"Sr.{self.nombre} su saldo disponible en su cuenta: {self.numc} es de {self.saldo} Bs.")
    def retirar(self):
        a=int(input("Monto a retirar en Bs:"))
        if self.saldo > a:
            ret=self.saldo-a
            print(f"Usted a retirado {a} Bs. Su saldo disponible es de {ret}")
        else:
            print("Usted no tiene los suficientes fondos, intentelo de nuevo")
            quit()

    
def registrarpersona():

    a = input("Ingrese su Nombre(s): ")
    b = input("Ingrese su Apellido: ")
    c = input("Ingrese su CI: ")
    x=random.randint(1011,10000)
    print(f"Su numero de cuenta es:{x}")
    e=int(input("Su saldo inicial es de en (Bs): " ))


    persona = cuenta(a, b, x ,c ,e)
    listadeclientes.append(persona)

def consultardatos():
    dato = int(input("Consulta de Datos, ingrese el Numero de Cuenta:"))
    for cuenta in listadeclientes:
        if cuenta.numc == dato:
             cuenta.csaldo()

def retirardinero():
    dato = int(input("Retiro de dinero, ingrese el Numero de Cuenta:"))
    for cuenta in listadeclientes:
        if cuenta.numc == dato:
            cuenta.csaldo()
            a=int(input("Monto a retirar en Bs:"))
            if cuenta.saldo > a:
                ret=cuenta.saldo-a
                print(f"Usted a retirado {a} Bs. Su saldo disponible es de {ret}")
                quit()
            else:
                print("Usted no tiene los suficientes fondos, intentelo de nuevo")
                quit()


def menu():
    opcion = 0
    while opcion != 4:
        print("*********************************")
        print("***BANCO MERCANTIL SANTA CRUZ***")
        print("*********************************")
        print("""
        1. Registrar Usuario
        2. Mostrar Datos de la Cuenta
        3. Retirar Dinero
        4. Salir
        """)
        opcion = int(input("Ingrese la opción..."))

        if opcion == 1:
            registrarpersona()
        if opcion == 2:
            consultardatos()
        if opcion == 3:
            retirardinero()
        if opcion == 4:
            quit()


menu()
```

para ser mas especifico es en esa parte, o sera que debo de hacer una funcion en la clase?, pero igual pierdo mi variable y se vuelve a iniciar desde 1001 ?
def registrarpersona():

```
    a = input("Ingrese su Nombre(s): ")
    b = input("Ingrese su Apellido: ")
    c = input("Ingrese su CI: ")
    x=random.randint(1011,10000)
    print(f"Su numero de cuenta es:{x}")
    e=int(input("Su saldo inicial es de en (Bs): " ))


    persona = cuenta(a, b, x ,c ,e)
    listadeclientes.append(persona)
```

O es que como digo, como puedo hacer que un numero vaya ascendiendo y que no pierda su recorrido para añadirlo dentro de un sistema de generacion de cuentas?
por ejemplo algo como:
Osvaldo cuenta:1001
Pedro cuenta:1002
Juan cuenta:1003
Tu amorsh: 1004

Answer (score 4):

Vamos a empezar por reducir el problema a la mínima expresión. La clase `Cuenta` (es convenio poner los nombres de clase en mayúscula) sólo va a tener el campo `numc` y `nombre`. Se trata además de que el `numc` no se reciba como parámetro en el constructor, sino que de algún modo el propio constructor lo asigne.

Es decir, nuestra clase sería algo así (le añado un método `__repr__()` para poder imprimir fácilmente objetos de este tipo, lo que ayuda a depurar)

```
class Cuenta:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numc = 1001      # Esto habrá que cambiarlo!

    def __repr__(self):
      return f"{self.nombre}:{self.numc}"
```

La forma de crear un objeto de este tipo será: `Cuenta("Pepito")` por ejemplo. Naturalmente tal como está ahora todas las cuentas creadas tendrán el mismo `numc` (1001) que no es lo que queremos.

Verificamos que todo funciona, aunque todas las cuentas reciben el mismo número de momento:

```
cuentas = [Cuenta(nombre) for nombre in ["Juan", "Ana", "Carlos", "Beatriz"]]
print(cuentas)
----------------
Salida: [Juan:1001, Ana:1001, Carlos:1001, Beatriz:1001]
```

Vamos a resolver el problema con diferentes técnicas, de menor a mayor sofisticación.

### Usar una variable global

Se puede tener un contador como variable global, e inicializarlo con el valor 1001. Después, dentro de `__init__()` se incrementará después de asignarlo. Hay que tener la precaución de declarar ese contador como `global` dentro de `__init__()` o de lo contrario Python asumirá que se trata de una variable local de esa función.

```
contador = 1001

class Cuenta:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        global contador
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numc = contador
        contador = contador + 1
    ...
```

Ahora cada cuenta tiene su propio número:

```
[Juan:1001, Ana:1002, Carlos:1003, Beatriz:1004]
```

### Atributo de clase

Las variables globales normalmente están desaconsejadas. Más que nada porque "contaminan" el espacio de nombres (si hay muchas variables globales puede ser difícil encontrar un nombre que no esté ya usado, y además no queda claro para qué se va a usar cada una).

Se puede en cambio tener atributos de clase, que son datos asociados con la clase en lugar de con el objeto. Son como variables globales, pero se escriben dentro de la clase y para acceder a ellas hay que poner el nombre de la clase delante (ej: `Cuenta.contador`) lo que evita la contaminación del espacio de nombres global y deja más claro además que se usará solo dentro de esa clase.

Se inicializaría y usaría así:

```
class Cuenta:
    contador = 1001

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numc = Cuenta.contador
        Cuenta.contador = Cuenta.contador + 1
```

Un pequeño problema de este enfoque es que si decides renombrar tu clase y en vez de llamarla `Cuenta` la llamas por ejemplo `Account`, tienes que acordarte también de cambiar todos los sitios donde aparezca `Cuenta.contador` por `Account.contador`

### Uso de una función generadora

Una función generadora es una función que contiene la instrucción `yield`, como por ejemplo la siguiente:

```
def contador(valor_inicial=0):
    c = valor_inicial
    while True:
        yield c
        c += 1
```

Este tipo de funciones cuando se ejecutan por su nombre (por ejemplo, escribiendo `contador()`, o `contador(1001)` ya que admite un parámetro) no se ejecutan en realidad, sino que retornan un *generador*.

Un generador es un tipo especial de objeto en Python sobre el que se puede efectuar la operación `next()`. Cuando lo haces, entonces sí comienza a ejecutarse el cuerpo de la función generadora, y se ejecutará hasta encontrar la instrucción `yield`, en cuyo momento se pausará retornando el valor especificado en `yield`. Cuando vuelvas a hacer `next()` sobre el generador, la función pausada reanudará su ejecución tras la instrucción `yield` y seguirá ejecutándose hasta encontrar el siguiente `yield`, etc.

Así que por ejemplo puede usarse así:

```
gen = contador(50)
print(next(gen))  # --> 50
print(next(gen))  # --> 51
print(next(gen))  # --> 52
```

En este caso va sacando valores correlativos porque así lo hemos programado dentro de la función generadora `contador()`, pero puedes escribir cualquier código para que genere cualquier secuencia de números (por ejemplo, puedes hacer que aumente de 5 en 5, o que se salte todos los múltiplos de 10, o que sólo genere números primos... al ser una función puedes complicarla lo que quieras y usar `yield` para retornar cada valor)

Gracias a este generador nuestra clase `Cuenta` puede quedar en la forma siguiente:

```
class Cuenta:
    _contador = contador(1001)

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numc = next(self._contador)

    ...
```

Aquí hago algunos "trucos". Primero declaro la variable `_contador` como un atributo de clase (le he puesto un `_` delante para que no se confunda con el nombre de la función generadora antes mostrada). Inicializo este atributo de clase con el generador creado al llamar a la función generadora `contador(1001)`.

Para asignar `self.numc` basta usar `next()` sobre ese atributo de clase. Pero en esta ocasión en vez de referirme a él como `Cuenta._contador` lo hago como `self._contador`.

Puedo hacer eso porque un atributo de clase es accesible tanto a través del nombre de la clase como a través del nombre del objeto, pero **sólo si no se va a modificar su valor**. En la solución anterior lo modificábamos (para sumarle 1) por lo que no podía usar `self.contador` allí y tuve que usar `Cuenta.contador`, pero en la solución con funciones generadoras no estamos modificando el valor de `self._contador` (siempre es el mismo valor, el valor del generador creado al llamar a la función generadora, nunca le asignamos otra cosa).

Eso nos evita tener que hacer explícito el nombre de la clase, por lo que esta solución seguirá funcionando incluso si decides cambiar el nombre de la clase `Cuenta` a `Account`.

### Igual a la anterior, pero sin escribir la función generadora

La función generadora `contador()` que hemos escrito en la solución anterior es tan simple (y tan frecuente su uso) que ya viene escrita en la biblioteca estándar python. Se llama `itertools.count()`, por lo que podemos reescribir nuestra solución en la forma siguiente:

```
import itertools

class Cuenta:
    _contador = itertools.count(1001)

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numc = next(self._contador)

    ...
```